# How to collapse an array by joining all strings, but leaving objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

While I'm sure I'm waay over-complicating things, I'm curious to know how I would "collapse" an array by combining all adjacent strings, but leaving objects as objects so that:

```
array = ["I","want","to",[Obj],"come","together"]
```

outputs

```
["I want to", [Obj], "come together"];
```

I feel like `array.reduce()` might be the ticket here, but I'm still wrapping my head around that function.

Comment: array.reduce() is powerful, but could reduce readability drastically if being misused..

Comment: @KenYo Yeah... almost every time I see someone use `reduce` I think, "Why can't you just make this readable?!!?!?" so I'm trying to get over my fear by overusing it ;-P

Comment: haha that's one way to go! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the array. If the current item and the last item in the accumulator (`r`) are strings, concatenate them. If not, push the current item to the accumulator:

```js
const array = ["I","want","to",[{}],"come","together"]

const isString = s => typeof s === 'string'

const result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(isString(o) && isString(r[r.length - 1])) {
    r[r.length - 1] = `${r[r.length - 1]} ${o}`
  } else {
    r.push(o)
  }

  return r
}, []) 

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```js
const array = ["I","want","to",{},"come","together"];

let outputArr = [];
let strArr = [];

array.forEach(elem => {
  if (typeof elem === 'string') {
    return strArr.push(elem);
  }
  
  outputArr.push(strArr.join(' '));
  strArr = [];
  outputArr.push(elem);
});

outputArr.push(strArr.join(' '));

console.log(outputArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanna go with the plain old `for-loop` :)

```js
var result = [], array = ["I","want","to",{a: 1, b:2},"come","together"];
var i=0;var str = "";
for(; i< array.length; i++){
  if(typeof array[i] === 'object' ){
     result.push(str);
     result.push(array[i]);
     str="";
     
   }else{
    str = str+" "+ array[i];
  }
}
if(i==array.length){
  result.push(str);
}
console.log(result);
```